# What is a difference in the order of "follow" and "index" in a robots meta tag?

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, meta-tags, meta-robots

What is the difference between

```
<meta name="robots" content="follow, index">
```

and

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

Would either create any issue for indexing or crawling?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between `follow, index` and `index, follow`. These would both permit robots to *index* content and *follow* links<sup>***1**</sup>. However, this is the default action for all bots, so the element is entirely superfluous.

(<sup>***1**</sup> But not because it contains the keywords `index` and `follow`, but because it does **not** contain the keywords `noindex` and/or `nofollow`.)

In fact, Google will simply ignore this element since `index` and `follow` are not one of the [listed values that it honours](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#directives) (and makes no mention of these values in its reference document). [Bingbot does mention you can use these values](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/which-robots-metatags-does-bing-support-5198d240), but again states that these are the default action, so are superfluous. Google does mention the `all` value (to indicate "no restrictions for indexing or serving"), if you want to explicitly put something in the tag, however, it also states that this "is the default value and has no effect", so again is entirely superfluous.

However, if you are also serving an `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header then this will override the robots meta tag in the HTML document.

Reference:

- [Google: Robots meta tag, data-nosnippet, and X-Robots-Tag specifications](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag)
- [Bing: Robots Metatags](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/which-robots-metatags-does-bing-support-5198d240)