# robots meta tag for specific web crawler

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, meta-tags, browsers, meta-robots

[Web crawler list](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/web-crawlers)

**What I want**

1. `noimageindex` (Indexation-controlling parameters) will only work for googlebot (2 : two meta tag - code below)
2. Others all crawlers (example as a YandexBot, Baiduspider) will work
   for (1: one meta tag - code below)

**Question is:**

*will below code will work for every crawler? if not, what is the easiest way to do it ?
Will need I to write for separate mea tag for every crawlers?*

In programming methodology there is a term overriding, That is why I am thinning (want to write meta tag) this way but I am not sure that will it work or not?

**Example Code**

```
1: <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" >

2: <meta  name="googlebot"  content="index, follow, noimageindex " >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
> <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow, noimageindex">
> ```

Yes, this will "work" as intended, but can be simplified. Googlebot will merge the two and "will use the sum of the negative directives", but there's nothing to merge.

However, `index` and `follow` are the default actions and will simply be ignored. See the following related question: [What is a difference in the order of "follow" and "index" in a robots meta tag?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133461/what-is-a-difference-in-the-order-of-follow-and-index-in-a-robots-meta-tag)

So, the above could be simplified to a single element:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noimageindex">
```

If you don't want images indexed by *any* bot (including Googlebot) that *might* support the `noimageindex` directive then you can "simplify" this further:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
```

Any bots (incl. Googlebot) that support `noimageindex` will honour it, those that don't will ignore it. (This does assume that any other bots implementation is similar to that of Googlebot.)

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag